# How to solve the "String" in "for each" loop

Tags: string, c++-cli, managed-c++

My task is to open multiple files after a button clicked, and read all those selected files.

I have found an example of foreach function in c#, but I would like to write it in C++. How should I actually to convert that?

It shows the error that `System::String`, cannot use this type here without top level '^'.

I'm still new with that. Does anyone can give suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Below is my written codes

```
Stream^ myStream;
OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1->Title = "open captured file";
openFileDialog1->Filter = "CP files (*.cp)|*.cp|All files (*.*)|*.*|txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
//openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;
openFileDialog1->Multiselect = true;

if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
{
    **for each (String line in openFileDialog1->FileName)** 
         System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("{0}",line);
    myStream->Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Container type returned, there is a `std::for_each` defined in `<algorithm>`-header.
The function Looks like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn);
```

You need to provide two `iterators`, one for the beginning of the Container and one for the end of the iterator. As a third Argument you can provide a function (function-object) and operate on the current argument.

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) for further reference.

As I got it from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilenames%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the property `SafeFileNames` returns an `array<String^>`.

`System::Array` provides a static method called `Array::ForEach`. You would need to call it like

```
System::Action<T> myAction; // You will Need to provide a function here to be used on every filename.
System::Array::ForEach(openFileDialog1->SafeFileNames, myAction);
```

This comes closest to `foreach` from C#.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for `System::Array::ForEach` and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zecdkyw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for `OpenFileDialog::SafeFileNames`.

Comment: This belongs to the `C++-STL` and so is portable. You can use it there without any concerns.

Comment: Is the the only way? I don't really understand this after I have gone through your given link. Sorry if this question is kinda stupid as I'm still quite new to it. Thank you very much for your time anyway.

Comment: Well, `std::foreach` comes closest to what you are looking for. See it this way: what you would provide inside `foreach() {}` in `C#` you provide as the third argument to `std::foreach`. Of course there would be the _normal_ way using iterators.